# Microsoft Azure cannot start debugging because of the rewrite rule

Tags: azure, https, web-config, url-rewrite-module

I'm trying to add an http to https redirection rule into my azure web roles web.config file but when I add it, It gives me the error which you can see in the image. I found out that the rule  line is responsible for this error.
What can I do?

[image: Http to Https redirection]

Servicedefinition.cscfg:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i've found the reason. It wasn't anything about azure. This rule also rewrites the path of the debugattach.aspx, this is the reason why visual studio cannot start debugging. To fix this issue I added this rule:

```
      <rule name="debug" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^debugattach\.aspx" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
        <action type="None" />
      </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does you cloud service definition have HTTPS setup locally.  The error suggests you haven't.  I would therefore use web.config transforms so that my locally running instance does not have the redirect and cloud deployments do or make https valid on your local debugging so that the debugger is connecting to the HTTPS.  I assume you have both an http and https endpoint in your definition.

Comment: Hi, how can i make https valid on my local debugging env.? Yeah I have both http and https endpoints. I'm adding my service configuration to the question.